# Getting error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device') on using python-inquirer for creating checkbox on command line in a while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to create checkbox inside a while loop using python-inquirer.
My code is as follows:

```
import inquirer
count = 5
while count > 1:
    questions = [inquirer.Checkbox('interests',
                                   message="Yes or no",
                                   choices=['Computers', 'Books'],)]
    answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
    print(answers['interests'])
    count -= 1
```

However I am getting the error -  (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
I am attaching the stack trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/test.py", line 7, in 
[?] Yes or no:

> o Computers
>      o Books
>       answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
>     File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/inquirer/prompt.py", line 14, in prompt
>       answers[question.name] = render.render(question, answers)
>     File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/inquirer/render/console/**init**.py", line 43, in render
>       return self._event_loop(render)
>     File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/inquirer/render/console/**init**.py", line 56, in _event_loop
>       self._process_input(render)
>     File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/inquirer/render/console/**init**.py", line 106, in _process_input
>       ev = self._event_gen.next()
>     File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/inquirer/events.py", line 22, in next
>       return KeyPressed(self._key_gen())
>     File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/readchar/readchar.py", line 88, in readkey
>       c1 = getchar()
>     File "/home/meghali/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/readchar/readchar_linux.py", line 12, in readchar
>       old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
>   termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
>   Process finished with exit code 1